# Tela de loading só quando necessário

Tags: jquery, css

Fiz uma tela de loading so que eu gostaria de fazer ela funcionar somente quando for uma ação demorada e não com qualquer carregamento.

JQUERY

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
});
    </script>
```

CSS

```
.loader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
    background: url("#{resource['/compracam/images/loadin2.gif']}") !important;
    opacity: .8;
}
```

Comment: Sua operações são assíncronas / Ajax ou síncronas?

Comment: Se não me engano Síncronas

Answer (score 0):

Você pode incluir a parte Html na master do seu projeto e incluir em seu css o código:

```
    .loader {
       ....
       display:none;
    }
```

E em suas telas que for utilizar você pode controlar a exibição da mesma através do código:

```
//Exibir
$(".loader").show();

//Esconder
$(".loader").hide();
```